# MySQL - Query search starts with number

Tags: mysql, sql, select, sql-like

I have the following MySQL query that searches through booth numbers ranging from 10 - 7000. The query is part of a jquery autocomplete. When the user begins typing in the number in the field I would like to search by the starting number - not if the complete number has that digit.

For example:

User is searching for booth 3458. When they start typing in the field "3" they are given the list of all booth numbers that contain the number 3 (ex. 1234, 1436, 1743, etc). I would rather have it show only booths that begin with the number typed in and drill down from that.

Here is the code:

```
if ($conn)
{
    $ac_term = "%".$_GET['term']."%";
    $query = "SELECT * FROM schedule where booth like :term";
    $result = $conn->prepare($query);
    $result->bindValue(":term",$ac_term);
    $result->execute();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You currently have wild cards on both ends of the search term. Just drop the wild card from the start of the search term, and you should be fine:

```
$ac_term = $_GET['term']."%";
```

Answer (score 2):

Just don't put a percent sign at the beginning:

```
$ac_term = $_GET['term']."%";
$query = "SELECT * FROM schedule where booth like :term";
$result = $conn->prepare($query);
$result->bindValue(":term",$ac_term);
$result->execute();
```

And +1 for using prepared statement!